# laravel 5.1 using Lazy Eager Loading usage

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1, lazy-loading

I'm working on a support ticket tool.
Table design at the moment:

```
tickets: |id|supp_id|title|user_id|...

ticket_replies: |id|ticket_id|user_id|text

files: |id|ticket_replie_id|name
```

model of ticket

```
public function ticket_replie() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ticket_replie', 'ticket_id', 'id');
}
```

model of ticket_replie

```
public function file() 
{
        return $this->hasOne('App\File', 'ticket_replie_id', 'id');
}
```

controller

```
$ticket = Auth::user()->tickets()->where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
   return view('protected.ticketDetail', compact('ticket'));
```

view

```
    ID: {{$ticket->id}}
    title: {{ $ticket->title}}<br>
    status: {{ returnStatus($ticket->status) }}<br>
    Ticket created: {{ $ticket->created_at }}<br>


    @if (!$ticket->supporter)
        supporter:-<br></br></br>
    @else
        supporter  {{ $ticket->supporter->username }}<br></br>
    @endif

    @foreach($ticket->ticket_replie as $reply)
        @if ($reply->file == null)
            reply text: {{ $reply->text }}</br>
        @else
            reply text: {{ $reply->text }}</br>
            file: <a href="/path/to/file/{!! $reply->file->name !!}">Download file</a><br>
        @endif
    reply created at: {{$reply->created_at}}</br></br>
    @endforeach
```

current screen of querys:
[image: querys debug]

Each ticket_replie can contain exact one "file", which stands for an attached file. As you may see in the querys this generates much load. Is there an way to use ([laravel Lazy Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)) to minimize amount of querys?

Ordering the ticket_replies by:

```
   $ticket = Auth::user()->tickets()->where('id', $id)->with(['ticket_replie.file'])->firstOrFail();

   $ticket->sortBy('ticket_replie.created_at');

   $ticket->values();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller something like this should do the job...

```
$ticket = Auth::user()->tickets()->where('id', $id)->with(['ticket_replie.file'])->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: I've edited code to `$ticket = Auth::user()->with(['tickets.ticket_replies.files'])->tickets()->where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();` but error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::tickets() is triggered.

Comment: What is the where clause for?

Comment: To retrieve only the ticket_replies for the current ticket.

Comment: I edited my answer although not sure it is exactly right. I would change to a scope to find the current ticket and you could add the `with` in the scope

Comment: Any tipp on how to get the ticket_replies ordered by date (oldest one to the top, newest at least). Did I need to use `sortByDesc()` or the `orderBy()` statement?

Comment: I would use an eloquent collection function rather than do it on the database should be easier and a bit more flexible. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-sortby. You have to use `$collection->values()` after doing the sort to maintain the ordering